# Transfer Dynamic Array to new Dynamic Array, Delete Dynamic array filled with Dynamic Objects

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic

If i create a dynamic array of Zebras, and then say, i make a new Temp array where i want to transfer the objects in the original array.

I then move pointer from original Array to Temp.  do i need to delete the old array items before move array = temp?

Also, I seem to leak but not sure why, i appear to delete both arrays and the pointers.

```
class Zebra {

public:
    //int age = 0;

};

int main() {
    
    Zebra** array = new Zebra * [10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        array[i] = new Zebra;
    }

    Zebra** temp = new Zebra * [20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        temp[i] = array[i];
    }
    // do i need to delete the old array items before move array = temp?
    array = temp;
    delete[]temp;
    temp=NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        delete[]array[i];
        array[i]=NULL;
    }

    
    delete[]array;

    array= NULL;
}
```

Comment: The obvious question is -- why are you not using `std::vector`?  Why are you trying to build a steering wheel instead of using the one that's already built into the car?

Comment: intro to CS, so learning pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have what you are deleting backwards, you want:

```cpp
    delete[] array;
    array = nullptr;
    
    array = temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        delete array[i];
        array[i] = NULL;
    }
    delete[] array;
    array = NULL;
```

Note, you also had a mismatched use of `delete[]` where `delete` alone should be used in freeing the `array[i]` elements.

*Why does this work this way?*

Originally you allocate for the pointer `array` creating a block of memory holding ten pointers to `Zebra`. When you then create `temp` twice as large as `array` and assign each pointer in `array` to `temp`, your `temp` holds the starting address for each `array[i]` (where `0 <= i < 10`).

All you do is `delete[] array`, which frees the block of memory holding the original storage for `10` pointers to `Zebra`. When you assign `array = temp;` now array points to the new block of memory of `20` pointers to `Zebra`.

So in your reallocation scheme, you have just created a larger block of pointers, assigned all from `array` to `temp`, deleted the original block of pointers, and assigned the new block of pointers to `array` (done). (essentially doing what `realloc()` does in C)

The full example would be:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Zebra {

public:
    //int age = 0;

};

int main() {
    
    Zebra **array = new Zebra*[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        array[i] = new Zebra;
    }

    Zebra **temp = new Zebra*[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        temp[i] = array[i];
    }
    
    delete[] array;
    array = nullptr;
    
    array = temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        delete array[i];
        array[i] = nullptr;
    }
    delete[] array;
    array = nullptr;
}
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

```
valgrind ./bin/zebra
==22402== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22402== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22402== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22402== Command: ./bin/zebra
==22402==
==22402==
==22402== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22402==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22402==   total heap usage: 13 allocs, 13 frees, 72,954 bytes allocated
==22402==
==22402== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==22402==
==22402== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22402== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation,  one last question. when you say "All you do is delete[] array, which frees the block of memory holding the original storage for 10 pointers " this does not actually delete the entire array including all 10 indexes, but it is just deleting the memory location that is pointing to the array consisting of 10 indexes?

Comment: Sure, happy to help further. When allocating for `pointer**` it is a 2-step process, you allocate a block of pointers, and then you loop allocating blocks of whatever type `pointer` is. When you allocate a new block of `pointer**`, all you do is copy the old element blocks to each pointer in the new block in turn, and then just delete the original block of pointers.

Comment: Recall you have copied the starting address of all `array[i]` you allocated with `temp[i] = array[i];`. So each `temp[i]` points to what was allocated with `array[i] = new Zebra;` When you `delete[] array;` all of the allocated blocks for `array[i]` are NOT effected. They are referred to now by `temp[i]`. So when you assign `array = temp;` you can refer to `temp[i]` (now `array[i]`) just as you would before and you do not delete the element blocks until you are done with that memory.

Comment: Great, thank you for the explanation! Very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your coding!